# Web app architecture- set a new password for a on-premises AD setup

Tags: passwords, web-application, active-directory, dmz

I need to implement a web app for a self-service change password use case for on-premise Active Directory users,
which is accessible over the internet.

The service must allow the users to set a new password, so I need to send the new password or a hash of it (if supported) to the on-premise AD. The user on the web is authenticated with another federated service and is not required to provide the AD user password. In this way the user can set a new password in the case he forgot it.

What is the best architecture?

- Host the service in a server in the DMZ and allow communication from the server to the AD.

-> I would like to avoid this because it require to open a TCP port, and probably it is not allowed by the company policy

- Host the service in a server in the cloud and create a server behind the firewall that communicates with the server via a message protocol (STOMP for example in RabbitMQ over WebSocket) in order to  acquire the requests from the web and apply to AD.
- Any alternatives/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't do this, the service used should authenticate the user by other means (2FA code, older password, security question, etc.)

If you are using AAD/O365/Hybrid you can also use the [SelfService password reset tool from Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/let-users-reset-passwords?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252flet-users-reset-their-own-passwords-in-office-365-5bc3f460-13cc-48c0-abd6-b80bae72d04a&view=o365-worldwide)

Or if you're inly on-prem you can check the following solutions:

[ADService Plus](https://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/) 
[Thycotic](https://thycotic.com/products/password-reset-server/)
[Adaxes](https://www.adaxes.com/active-directory_self-service-password-reset.htm)